# Rails Form_for "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" after logging out(sessions#destroy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

After logging in and then logging out, I keep getting the error that the first argument in the form cannot be nil or empty. How do I solve this issues while still maintaining the disappearance of the form when a user is logged in?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li>
        <% if current_user %>
        <li>
          <li><%= link_to "Profile Summary", current_user %></li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <li><%= link_to "Edit personal details", edit_user_path %></li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <li><%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
        </li>
        <% else %>
        <li><%= form_for @user do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", class: "form-control"  %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit 'Login', class: "btn btn-default" %>
          <% end %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
        <li>
          <li><%= link_to "New User", new_user_path %></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Opinions', profile_path %></li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <li><%= link_to 'About',contact_path %></li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Contact', contact_path %></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
```

The following is my Users controller

```
      def new
@user = User.new
  end
def show
@user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  flash[:success] = "Account Created. Please Login"
  redirect_to profile_path
else
  flash[:danger] = "Please fill in all your information"
  render :new
end
end
def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update(user_params)
  redirect_to @user
  flash[:success] = 'User profile successfully updated.'
else
  render :edit
end
end
def profile
end
```

And this is the sessions controller

```
    def create
user = User.find_and_authenticate_user(user_params)

if user
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  flash[:success] = "You are logged in."
  #redirect_to refers to a get command by default as it is
  #the only command to display. *_path is a combination of
  #the RESTful actions
  redirect_to profile_path
else
  flash[:danger] = "Credentials Invalid!!"
  redirect_to login_path
end
end

def destroy
session[:user_id] = nil
flash[:success] = "User logged out!!"
redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Why not try with form_tag and pass email and password and authenticate/create the user.

Comment: Try `<%= form_for resource, as: resource_name do |f| %>`

Comment: Sorry just did a slight edit of the original code. Do I still try form_tag?

Comment: You need to show us how u have defined @user in your controller... as your user instance variable is nil at the time of logout

Answer (score 0):

As you have not described your current_user helper method, it is a bit difficult to answer.

But still, as per my understanding current_user method will give the user that is signed in rather than giving a boolean value.

If that is the case, for a new user, show action will not receive any session Id and as a result, @user will be null. Now, your condition will fail and else part will give you the null or empty error.

To get over that, you can either compare like `session[:user_id] == @user.id` in your helper method and return the boolean value as a result or use direct comparison with session ID in your view if the helper is returning complete logged in user object.

Hope this helps..